# Using a user key in a service request?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am coding a SOAP/WSDL Web Service.

And I am connecting to the server via:

Service s = Service.create(url, qname);

So for authentification I have a user key.

How to put it as attribute in the Service request?

Comment: It is necessary to understand how the user key is to be provided.  The straightforward ways of applying authentication are at the (HTTP) transport level and at message level (ws-security).  Is there a constraint that forces you to use one or the other or are you just wanting to experiment?